# What to do when an installer is not available for Ubuntu

Tags: package-management, software-installation, debian

If I find a program that I would like to install on Ubuntu, but there is only an installer available for Debian or another Debian derivative such as Mint, what can I do? Is there a way to use a pure Debian installer to install on Ubuntu?

I have seen some references to using dpkg or gdebi to find the right dependencies for a local copy of the installer. Is this workable solution?

Comment: Ubuntu is a Debian derivative too, so it's not clear why you think it will work for others but not Ubuntu. If you provide specific details of the problem, we can provide clear answers.

Comment: Mint is a derivative of Ubuntu which in turn is a derivative of Debian. The installer must work if there's no dependency issues or conflicts with already installed packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both `dpkg -i` first and then `apt-get install -f` (alternatively just `gdebi`).

If the dependencies are statisfied, then you're all set. If not, you might have to fullfill them manually, by installing other packages.

The less foreign packages you install, the better.

Comment: You can also use `sudo apt install /path/to/deb.file`. Apt does local install now, and will routinely handle all dependencies.